php readfile() problem on download content (i read all related posts before send it)
I'm having trouble creating a secure download on my site, it's not uploaded yet and it's currently being tested on the xampp server on my PC. It should be noted that my operating system is Windows 11
this is my code:
user click on a download link (jquery):
$(document).on('click','.downfile',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var reqfile=$(this).next().val();
  $.post('php/downloadfile.php',{
    reqfile:reqfile
    },function(data){});
});

I divided the download file into two parts because someone on this site said that this might be the problem.
so first part is:
<?php
$file_path = "../uploads/".$_POST['reqfile'];
if (file_exists($file_path)){
  $_SESSION['download']=$file_path;
  header('location: startdownload.php');
}
?>

<?php
session_start();
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: '. mime_content_type($_SESSION['download']));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($_SESSION['download']).'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($_SESSION['download']));
ob_clean();
flush();
ob_end_flush();
readfile($_SESSION['download']);
exit;
?>

and result is:
firefox developer mode
As you can see, the file is loaded correctly but not downloaded.
And the interesting thing is that the same code was working last week and the file was being downloaded. I have only made a small change in the code that has nothing to do with this section and moved the files folder one level further, for example:
It was uploads/1/test.jpg and now it is uploads/1/1/test.jpg
please help me to solve this problem.

You are making your POST request via AJAX in the background - so that is where the response "lands" as well. You don't get an automatic "save as" dialog in that scenario, your JavaScript would now be responsible for processing the response any further. (And there really is no way that this was working any differently last week.)

Content-Transfer-Encoding is not an HTTP header

I divided the download file into two parts because someone on this site said that this might be the problem...no, nothing to do with that. That seems to be just creating an extra redirect, and thus the overhead of an extra HTTP request, for no useful reason. Reduce complexity and possible points of failure by just sticking to one request. And then follow other examples online (such as in the duplicate questions above, and other similar ones) which already show you how to deal with a file download using ajax functionality. This is not a new question, by a long, long way

Security issue! Don't use a POST argument as part of a filename without path restrictions! With that code, an attacker can easily access arbitrary files on the server!
